# Import contacts from outlook to your php application

Tags: php, outlook

I am trying to import contact from outlook into my php application. I am using REST API call. Here's my code:

```
$access_token = "TOKEN";
$api_url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/contact.de3413e6000000000000000000000000?access_token='.$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

curl_close($curl);
```

However it does not work as I am not able to get the access token.

Comment: i also downloaded a code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310 .but it retreives only the photograph and name from the users profile after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CloudSponge PHP library:
https://github.com/cloudsponge/cloudsponge-lib-php/

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.